# Why was Alice certain her Niffin form would kill the beast

Tags: magical-theory, the-magicians

In Season 2 Episode 3, Alice deliberately transformed herself into a Niffin so that it/her would kill The Beast.  From what I understand the Niffin's have their own personality and desires.  Why was Alice certain her Niffin form would come back and kill The Beast?

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but from what I remember of the book she could've just been desperate. Even if she wasn't certain, they were running out of options.